# How to get a the name of the threadgroup a current thread is in

Tags: java, multithreading

In my main method, I have done the following:

```
ThreadGroup human = new ThreadGroup("Humans");
Thread s = new Thread(human, new Student(ca));
```

When I print out the the name of the group the thread is in by `System.out.println(s.getThreadGroup().getName());` then it prints out Humans. But when I go to the Student class and do the following: `String threadGroupName = this.getThreadGroup().getName();` and print out the String variable, it prints out `main`. I dont understand this as upon creation of this thread, I have speicified it to be in the Humans thread group so why is it saying it's in the main thread group?

Comment: Has one of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 1):

s is the new thread you created. Whereas, your Student instance is **s.target**

When you ran the Thread constructor to create s, you injected the new Runnable (Student instance in your case).

Thread s = new Thread(human, new Student(ca));

**s is thread-x and Student is thread-y. They are separate instances.**

s.target is the new Runnable Student you had created.

Hope this helps.

**If you want to have the same thread group, you have to pass the "Humans" ThreadGroup into the Student thread.** Try this:

```
public class ThreadGroups {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ThreadGroup human = new ThreadGroup("Humans");
        Thread s1 = new Student(human, "studentThread");
        Thread s = new Thread(human, s1);
        System.out.println(s.getThreadGroup().getName());
        System.out.println(s1.getThreadGroup().getName());
        s.start();
    }

    static class Student extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(this.getThreadGroup().getName());
        }

        public Student(ThreadGroup group, String name) {
            super(group, name);
        }

        public Student() {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay I think I know what you mean. So to make them refer to the same instance, should I create a student Object `Student studentThread = new Student(ca);` and then pass this obj into the parameter of the Thread constructor?

Comment: I am assuming that Student extends Thread right? You want the Student and your thread s to have the same group right?

Comment: I added a sample code in my answer to get the same ThreadGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Student` extends from `Thread`, otherwise there wouldn't be a `getThreadGroup` method to call. The reason why you get `main` as result is that you haven't passed `human` to your instance of `Student`, so that thread is assigned to the main-group.

Here is an example class that should show you the effect:

```
public class ThreadGroupTest {

    public final static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ThreadGroup human = new ThreadGroup("Humans");
        Student student = new Student(null);
        Thread s = new Thread(human, student);
        synchronized(student) {
            s.start();
            student.wait(1000);
        }
        System.out.println(s.getThreadGroup().getName());
        student.printThisThreadGroup();
        student.printCurrentThreadGroup();
        synchronized(student) {
            student.killed = true;
            student.notifyAll();
        }

    }

    static class Student extends Thread {
        Student(ThreadGroup group) {
            super(group, (Runnable) null);
        }

        boolean killed;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("running in group '" + Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName() + "'");
            try {
                while (!killed) {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        notifyAll();
                        wait(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

        }

        public void printThisThreadGroup() {
            System.out.println("this.getThreadGroup: " + this.getThreadGroup().getName());
        }

        public void printCurrentThreadGroup() {
            System.out.println("CurrentThread: " + Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName());
        }

    }
}
```

The code is a more complete example of your implementation, you can see a constructor of student that takes a ThreadGroup as parameter which currently is `null`. That's the equivalent of using the default-constructor which I assume you used (it's not part of your example code).

When executing this code you get the following output:

```
running in group 'main'
Humans
this.getThreadGroup: main
CurrentThread: main
```

If you change `null` to `human` the output will change to the following:

```
running in group 'Humans'
Humans
this.getThreadGroup: Humans
CurrentThread: main
```

Here `this.getThreadGroup` provides you with the correct group but it's not the final answer, yet. Instead of extending from `Thread` you should implement `Runnable` and pass that to a newly instantiated `Thread` I suppose you did it because of your requirement to get the thread's ThreadGroup, but that's not required as you can see in Student's `run`-method how you can achieve that by calling `Thread.currentThread()` returning the thread you're currently in. You can also see that using this still is a bit tricky, because you still get `main`  as result if you call that method from a different method (the main method here) running in a different thread (again the `main`-thread leading to `main` as result in the last line of the four output lines.